# Create embebbed documents to load to mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

I have 3 JSONs - *flight*, *airplane* and *airport*. I want to embed *airplane* and *airport* into *flight* when a key in *flight* is the same in *airplane* and *airport*. How can I create an embedded JSON to load to MongoDB?

**JSON airplane:**

```
{  
  "tailnum":"N14334",
  "issue_data":"09/02/1997",
  "status":"Valid",
  "year":"1986\r",
  "type":"Corporation",
  "engine_type":"Turbo-Jet",
  "model":"737-3TO",
  "aircraft_type":"Fixed Wing Multi-Engine",
  "airline":"Continental Air Lines Inc.",
  "manufacturer":"BOEING"
}
```

**JSON airport:**

```
{  
  "idairport":"00M",
  "airport":"Thigpen ",
  "city":"Bay Springs",
  "state":"MS",
  "country":"USA",
  "latitude":"31,95376472",
  "longitude":"-89,23450472"
}
```

**JSON flight:**

```
{  
  "id_flight":1,
  "year":1995,
  "month":1,
  "dayofmonth":2,
  "dayofweek":1,
  "deptime":1148,
  "crsdeptime":1145,
  "arrtime":1428,
  "crsarrtime":1435,
  "flightnum":"1845",
  "tailnum":"N14334",
  "actualelapsedtime":100,
  "crselapsedtime":110,
  "airtime":80,
  "arrdelay":-7,
  "depdelay":3,
  "origin":"00M",
  "dest":"PHL",
  "distance":678,
  "taxiin":5,
  "taxiout":15,
  "cancelled":"0",
  "diverted":"0"
}
```

So in JSON *flight* where is `origin`, I want to add the document *airport* and when is `tailnum`, I want to add the document *airplane* like an embedded way.

Comment: It would be better if you share sample JSON and elaborate what do you want to achieve exactly. Also, I assume you already have data and you want to save in this embedded way. Right?

Comment: yes i already edit the post sorry